# Is it "nos de" or "nosotros de"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I've heard the pronoun "nos" and I don't quite understand how to use it in comparison to "nosotros". Is it "nos de" or "nosotros de" for possession?

Comment: Ugh, apparently neither is correct. Please try to give us an approximate example of what you are trying to say, so we can help you.

Comment: Are you trying to "We of... [insert place here]"?

Comment: Without context it's gonna be difficult as @Rodrigo said none are correct but in some context both could be correct (but perhaps not as possessive) `Esperemos que el jefe **nos de** permiso` or  `¿de dónde viene ustedes? **Nosotros [venimos] de** Colombia`

Comment: *Nos* is the [clitic, non-emphatic](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/clitics.htm) form of *nosotros*, used for the 1st person plural verb objects, never following a preposition. The explanation of possessive use is on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For possesion is `nuestro`, `nuestra`, `nuestros`, `nuestras`.

**Example:**

Ese es nuestro coche.

Nuestra casa está en Barcelona.

Nuestros padres viven en Madrid.

Nuestras hermanas son gemelas.

Comment: Estás dejando fuera el `de nosotros`, que también puede ser válido en algunos contextos.

Comment: @Rafael ¿Puedes dar algún ejemplo? A mí no se me ocurre ninguno.

Comment: @Gorpik aparte de las ocasiones en que es intercambiable con _nuestro_ --la casa es _de nosotros_, v. la definición misma de [nuestro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qhpp2r0)--, en construcciones donde el _de_ es normativo y no implica posesión: cada uno _de nosotros_.

Comment: @Rafael Me refería solo al significado posesivo, del que tratan la pregunta y respuesta. *La casa es de nosotros* no me parece gramaticalmente correcto, igual que no lo es *la casa es de yo*.

Comment: @Gorpik será una diferencia regional? A diferencia de _nuestro(a)_, la deifinición de [_mío(a)_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PLHnXR2) del DLE no ofrece ni _de yo_ ni _de mí_ como significado (que a mi también me _parece_ gramaticalmente incorrecto). Nota tangencial: [interesante discusión sobre nuestro/de nosotros](http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/especulo/cajetin/dmio.html) ante adverbios de lugar.

Comment: @Rafael Ciertamente, debería haber escrito *de mí*, no *de yo*..

Comment: En cuanto a *de nosotros*, en las 200 primeras coincidencias de Google solo he encontrado su uso como posesivo en la letra de alguna canción. Me da que es un uso coloquial en alguna zona, tal vez donde vives tú se da, como apuntas.